# Access container end point in multi-container environment using Application Load Balancer DNS in aws

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, prometheus-java

Hello all so I have a Springboot application that is fetching data from aws S3 and I am using Prometheus to monitor the Springboot app. In ECS I create a task definition and added both the images with their respective port mappings then I created a service and a Application Load Balancer in which I added Springboot app image to load balance and also created target group to forward traffic to 8080 on which my spring app is running all of this is working fine I am able to hit my spring app endpoint by using ALB DNS but is there nay way with which  can access the Prometheus dashboard which is on port 9090

I tried adding listener 90 to ALB and created separate target group to redirect traffic to 9090 I didn't give any error but even tough how to access the Prometheus dashboard because the DNS is itself working as 8080

Answer (score 0):

> "I tried adding listener 90 to ALB and created separate target group to redirect traffic to 9090"

That's exactly what you would need to do.

> "I didn't give any error but even tough how to access the Prometheus dashboard because the DNS is itself working as 8080"

This last statement is really confusing. DNS doesn't work on a port. When you don't specify a port, it does the default HTTP port which is `80`. You added another listener on port `90`. So you need to add port `90` to your URL in the web browser to access that listener: `http://load-balancer-dns-name:90`

Comment: Thank you for the reply 'http://load-balancer-dns-name:90' I tried this too but it didn't work and by the second statement I meant that if I hit the DNS only it redirects to 8080. So currently I am trying to integrate NGINX reverse proxy to get around this issue will update the results.

Answer (score 0):

OK so this might not be a direct answer but for anyone experiencing the same issue I later integrated Nginx as reverse proxy in my project and with that integrated is works fine now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).